# How to switch string with HTML tags to clear string in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, ios10

I have old code:

```
   func htmlToText(encodedString:String) -> String?
{
    let encodedData = encodedString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    do
    {
        return try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:NSUTF8StringEncoding], documentAttributes: nil).string
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return nil
    }
}
```

and I want to translate it to swift 3, now i have:

```
let encodedData = encodedString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    do
   {
        return try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:String.Encoding.utf8], documentAttributes: nil).string
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return nil
    }
```

This code generate error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue unsignedIntegerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000251d30'
I have no idea what could went wrong. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.Encoding` is a Swift struct, which cannot be passed to Objective-C world. When Swift find such things in `Any`, it generates `_SwiftValue` which is completely useless in Objective-C.

Try this:

```
return try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: [
    NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
    NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
], documentAttributes: nil).string
```